# Swing Line break - overriding graphics draw

Tags: swing, drawstring

In the code, I am reading an xml file and painting the contents accordingly on a JPanel.
If the file contains a tag `<LineBreak/>` I am supposed to insert a Line Break before the next word. 
I thought I could use a

```
g.drawString(..)
```

but that requires that I know what follows the break, which in this case, I do not.
Is there any other way to do this by overriding the draw method?

Really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) ([g.getFontMetrics()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics%28%29)) to determine the number of vertical pixels needed to display a line of text.  When you call drawString to paint the second line of text, you must pass a `y` value large enough that the second line of text is drawn below the first line of text.

```
String[] lines = myStringFromXmlDoc.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
int verticalOffset = 0; // your starting offset would probably be more dynamic
foreach(String line : lines)
{
    g.drawString(line, 0, verticalOffset);
    // use FontMetrics to implement calcLineHeight for yourself
    int currentLineHeight = calcLineHeight(line, g);
    verticalOffset += currentLineHeight;
}
```

Edit:

Also see [java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html) for a possibly useful utility class.